# Регулярка, чтобы вытянуть JS код со страницы

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

помогите из html страницы выбрать определенный кусок js кода.

Для примера:
 1. Есть страница: https://detail.1688.com/offer/543407452177.html
 2. В теле страницы есть код http://prntscr.com/n3iv3k

Нужно вытянуть как то две этих переменных в виде массивов.
Все это нужно реализовать на PHP

Answer (score 1):

```
function get_page_from_ip($url,$ip)
{
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Internet Explorer/6.0 (X11; U; Windows XP SP2; en-US; rv:1.7.2) Gecko/20040804');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.7,de-de;q=0.3',
'Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5',
'X-Forwarded-For: '. $ip));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $page;
}
$html = get_page_from_ip('https://detail.1688.com/offer/543407452177.html', '19.19.19.19');

$html = preg_match_all('#<script type="text/javascript">(.+?)</script>#is', $html, $arr);
$js_arr[] = stristr($arr[1][1], 'var iDetailData', true);
$js_arr[] = str_replace($js_arr[0], '', $arr[1][1]);


echo '<pre>';
print_r($js_arr);
echo '</pre>';
```

[раз](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHot9.png)

[два](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWVNP.png)

Comment: Dizzy221, большое спасибо